# Recursive data in JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, recursion

```
{
"groups": [
    {
        "name": "Event",
        "groups": [
            {
                "name": "Service",
                "subscriptions": [
                    {
                        "topic": "SERVICE_STATUS_PRESETS"
                    },
                    {
                        "topic": "AIRCRAFT_ACTIVATION",

                    },
                    {
                        "topic": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Enquiries",
        "groups": [
            {
                "name": "Service-related",
                "subscriptions": [
                    {

                        "topic": "PROMO_CODES_REQUESTS",

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"subscriptions": [
    {
        "topic": "BANNERS",
    },
    {
        "topic": "DOCUMENTS",
    },
    {
        "topic": "USER",
    }
]
```

}

OK guys I have such JSON structure what I need is to: return all topics in array, in this example it will be:

**["SERVICE_STATUS_PRESETS", "AIRCRAFT_ACTIVATION", "OUT_OF_SERVICE", "PROMO_CODES_REQUESTS", "BANNERS", "DOCUMENTS", "USER"]**

I try recursive calls like this, though I only get last three records:

```
getRecursive() {
if (Array.isArray(data)) {
       for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         if (data[i].subscriptions) {
           return data[i].subscriptions.map((val: SubscriptionGroupDetails) => val.topic);
         } else if (data[i].groups) {
           return this.getAllTopics(data[i].groups);
         }
       }
     }
     if (data && data.groups) {
      return this.getAllTopics(data.groups);
     }
     return data.subscriptions.map((val: SubscriptionGroupDetails) => val.topic);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: @Teemu: that doesn't look particularly relevant.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Maybe not, but there's no recursion (at least obvious) in the provided example, maybe the answers in the linked post give some ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and check

- if the handed over data is not an object for checking, then return with empty array,
- if the object has the wanted property, then return an array with the value of `topic`,
- or get the values and make a recursive call with the function and return an array with the result of it.

```js
function getTopics(object) {
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return [];
    if ('topic' in object) return [object.topic];
    return Object.values(object).reduce((r, v) => [...r, ...getTopics(v)], []);
}

var data = { groups: [{ name: "Event", groups: [{ name: "Service", subscriptions: [{ topic: "SERVICE_STATUS_PRESETS" }, { topic: "AIRCRAFT_ACTIVATION" }, { topic: "OUT_OF_SERVICE" }] }] }, { name: "Enquiries", groups: [{ name: "Service-related", subscriptions: [{ topic: "PROMO_CODES_REQUESTS" }] }] }], subscriptions: [{ topic: "BANNERS" }, { topic: "DOCUMENTS" }, { topic: "USER" }] },
    result = getTopics(data);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = {"groups":[{"name":"Event","groups":[{"name":"Service","subscriptions":[{"topic":"SERVICE_STATUS_PRESETS"},{"topic":"AIRCRAFT_ACTIVATION"},{"topic":"OUT_OF_SERVICE"}]}]},{"name":"Enquiries","groups":[{"name":"Service-related","subscriptions":[{"topic":"PROMO_CODES_REQUESTS"}]}]}],"subscriptions":[{"topic":"BANNERS"},{"topic":"DOCUMENTS"},{"topic":"USER"}]};

const searchTopics = (obj) => objectScan(['**.topic'], { rtn: 'value' })(obj);

console.log(searchTopics(data));
/* => [
  'USER',
  'DOCUMENTS',
  'BANNERS',
  'PROMO_CODES_REQUESTS',
  'OUT_OF_SERVICE',
  'AIRCRAFT_ACTIVATION',
  'SERVICE_STATUS_PRESETS'
] */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
function getTopics(obj){
   if(typeof obj !== 'object') return [];
   if(obj.topic) return [obj.topic];
   var res = [];
   for(var i in obj){
     res.push(...getTopics(obj[i]));
   }
   return res;
}
```

Working example:

```js
const topics = {
"groups": [
    {
        "name": "Event",
        "groups": [
            {
                "name": "Service",
                "subscriptions": [
                    {
                        "topic": "SERVICE_STATUS_PRESETS"
                    },
                    {
                        "topic": "AIRCRAFT_ACTIVATION",

                    },
                    {
                        "topic": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Enquiries",
        "groups": [
            {
                "name": "Service-related",
                "subscriptions": [
                    {

                        "topic": "PROMO_CODES_REQUESTS",

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"subscriptions": [
    {
        "topic": "BANNERS",
    },
    {
        "topic": "DOCUMENTS",
    },
    {
        "topic": "USER",
    }
]
}

function getTopics(obj){
  if(typeof obj !== 'object') return [];
  if(obj.topic) return [obj.topic];
  var res = [];
  for(var i in obj){
    res.push(...getTopics(obj[i]));
  }
  return res;
}


console.log(getTopics(topics));
```

Answer (score 1):

This version that takes a functional approach if you are interested. There are others above but this is just another way to look at it.

```
const recursion = object => Object.entries(object).map(([a, b]) => {
  if (a === 'topic') return b;
  if (Array.isArray(b)) return b.map(recursion);
  return [];
}).flat(Infinity);

recursion(obj);
```

Comment: Trade out `map()` for `flatMap()` (and remove `.flat(Infinity)` in this function for a slight performance boost: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Added another way of doing it with *.reduce()*

You can create an empty array of `topics` and then navigate through your nested structure recursively, adding a topic each time you come across it, using the javascript [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to cycle through any nested `groups` or `subscriptions`.

```
let topics = [];

let findTopics = obj => {
   if (obj.groups) {
      obj.groups.forEach(findTopics);
   }
   if (obj.subscriptions) {
      obj.subscriptions.forEach(findTopics);
   }
   if (obj.topic) {
      topics.push(obj.topic);
   }
}

findTopics(data);
```

Or a possibly neater way using [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
let findTopicsRecursive = (topics, obj) => {
   if (obj.groups) {
      topics = obj.groups.reduce(findTopicsRecursive, topics);
   }
   if (obj.subscriptions) {
      topics = obj.subscriptions.reduce(findTopicsRecursive, topics);
   }
   if (obj.topic) {
      topics.push(obj.topic);
   }
   return topics;
}

let findTopics = data => findTopicsRecursive([], data);

let topics = findTopics(data);
```

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky you mean to say that this code is very dependent on a specific data structure?

Comment: Yes this what I mean indeed

Comment: @calarin: See some of the other answers for techniques that do this more generically.

Comment: @scottsauyet YosefTukachinsky Yes good point - I see what you mean!